# Mocking os.environ with python unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, environment-variables, python-unittest

I am trying to test a class that handles for me the working directory based on a given parameter. To do so, we are using a class variable to map them.

When a specific value is passed, the path is retrieved from the environment variables (See `baz` in the example below). This is the specific case that I'm trying to test.

I'm using Python `3.8.13` and `unittest`.

##### I'm trying to avoid:

- I don't want to mock the `WorkingDirectory.map` dictionary because I want to make sure we are fetching from the `environ` with that particular variable (`BAZ_PATH`).
- Unless is the only solution, I would like to avoid editing the values during the test, i.e I would prefer not to do something like: `os.environ["baz"] = DUMMY_BAZ_PATH`

##### What I've tried

I tried mocking up the `environ` as a dictionary as suggested in other publications, but I can't make it work for some reason.

```py
# working_directory.py
import os


class WorkingDirectory:
    map = {
        "foo": "path/to/foo",
        "bar": "path/to/bar",
        "baz": os.environ.get("BAZ_PATH"),
    }

    def __init__(self, env: str):
        self.env = env
        self.path = self.map[self.env]

    @property
    def data_dir(self):
        return os.path.join(self.path, "data")

    # Other similar methods...
```

Test file:

```py
# test.py

import os
import unittest

from unittest import mock

from working_directory import WorkingDirectory

DUMMY_BAZ_PATH = "path/to/baz"


class TestWorkingDirectory(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"BAZ_PATH": DUMMY_BAZ_PATH})
    def test_controlled_baz(self):
        wd = WorkingDirectory("baz")
        self.assertEqual(wd.path, DUMMY_BAZ_PATH)
```

##### Error

As shown in the error, `os.environ` doesn't seem to be properly patched as it returns `Null`.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_controlled_baz (test_directory_structure_utils.TestWorkingDirectory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py", line 1756, in _inner
    return f(*args, **kw)
  File "~/Projects/dummy_project/tests/unit/test_directory_structure_utils.py", line 127, in test_controlled_baz
    self.assertEqual(wd.path, DUMMY_BAZ_PATH)
AssertionError: None != 'path/to/baz'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 136 tests in 0.325s

FAILED (failures=1, skipped=5)
```

This seems to be because the `BAZ_PATH` doesn't exist actually. However, I would expect this to be OK since is being patched.

When, in the mapping dictionary, `"baz": os.environ.get("BAZ_PATH")`, I repalce `BAZ_PATH` for a variable that actually exist in my environment, i.e `HOME`, it returns the actual value of `HOME` instead of the `DUMMY_BAZ_PATH`, which lead me to think that I'm definetely doing something wrong patching

```
AssertionError: '/Users/cestla' != 'path/to/baz'
```

##### Expected result

Well, obviously, I am expecting the `test_controlled_baz` passes succesfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem is that you added map as a static variable.
Your patch works correctly as you can see here:

[patch actually works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1911.png)

The problem is that when it runs it's already too late because the map variable was already calculated (before the patch).
If you want you can move it to the **init** function and it will function correctly:

```
class WorkingDirectory:

def __init__(self, env: str):
    self.map = {
        "foo": "path/to/foo",
        "bar": "path/to/bar",
        "baz": os.environ.get("BAZ_PATH")
    }
    self.env = env
    self.path = self.map[self.env]
```

If for some reason you wish to keep it static, you have to also patch the object itself.
writing something like this will do the trick:

```
class TestWorkingDirectory(unittest.TestCase):
@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"BAZ_PATH": DUMMY_BAZ_PATH})
def test_controlled_baz(self):
    with mock.patch.object(WorkingDirectory, "map", {
        "foo": "path/to/foo",
        "bar": "path/to/bar",
        "baz": os.environ.get("BAZ_PATH")
    }):
        wd = WorkingDirectory("baz")
        self.assertEqual(wd.path, DUMMY_BAZ_PATH)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Moving the `map` within the `__init__` worked. The use of it is only within the class, so there's no need to have it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

That's not directly answer to your question but a valid answer either way imo:
Don't try to patch that (it's possible, but harder and cumbersome).
Use config file for your project.

e.g. use **pyproject.toml** and inside configure the pytest extension:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
env=[
"SOME_VAR_FOR_TESTS=some_value_for_that_var"
]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Will this work with `unittest` too ? I've tried, but I can't make it work. I wonder if is something I'm doing wrong or is just for `pytest` and not for `unittest`

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. It's for pytest. You can actually mix up unittest with pytest and make it work, but I'd stay as far away from this stupid idea as possible.  @nimrod-shanny gave a v.good answer imo.

Comment: No worries, thanks again for your answer. Is good to know for other cases :)